# Dynamically change of Min and Max in JQuery using Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have developed Range Slider in visualforce which contains static resource which contains jqury.
I am using the same static resource and create another Range Slider but this time i want to change MIN and Max of Jquery.
If you have any suggestion kindly tell me

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" sidebar="false">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.Main}" />

    <style>
        .sliderHeight
        {
            height:10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!$Resource.jQRangeSlidermin}"/>

    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <div id="slider" class="sliderHeight"></div>
    <script>
        $("#slider").rangeSlider();
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using the jQuery UI slider use the setter

> Get or set the min option, after initialization:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "min", 10 );
```

or for the Range:

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0, 10 );
$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1, 50 );
```

0 sets the first handle
1 sets the second handle

or as an array

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "values", [ 55, 105 ] );
```

Outlined clearly in the documentation here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-min

Comment: :will it work??

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan - Did you try it?